# Set model velocity via msgs in Gazebo 6

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I need to move a model smoothly from keyboard. For this I need to set (maybe, learn) velocity of a model via messages.
In Messages API I found only static pose arguments. In a few places on the internet I saw some comments about "geometrymsgs/Twist" topic, but they look outdated as in Gazebo 6 there isn't anything similar.

So how Can I do this without any plugins, using just messages?

Thanks for the feedback!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12160/set-model-velocity-via-msgs-in-gazebo-6/) by [alexorex](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2340/alexorex/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can apply a [wrench](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e4b49fd4734aac84389c47ee76bd8a0bb4c6d081/gazebo/msgs/wrench.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) to a link using a topic with the following format:

`~/WORLD_NAME/MODEL_NAME/LINK_NAME/wrench`

Replace `WORLD_NAME` with the name of the world (usually `default`)

Replace `MODEL_NAME` with the name of the model.

Replace `LINK_NAME` with the name of the link on which to apply the force.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexorex](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2340/alexorex/) on 2015-12-10**:
Thanks, it worked!

Now maybe you know where I can publish the WrenchStamped messages, it would be much more effective? ".../wrench_stamped" didn't work.
And how to stop the movement, because applying the same force backwards seems irrational?

And, optionally, how to learn/limit the velocity of the model?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-12-11**:
I have been giving you advice based on the [ApplyForceTorque widget](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/b60a5186d0008a915ccdc632f17df5d09ca33c24/gazebo/gui/ApplyWrenchDialog.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). You might be better served looking at that code for examples.

**Comment by [alexorex](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2340/alexorex/) on 2015-12-14**:
From the file I learned that the values of Wrench can be in the thousands, unlike joints force in my previous experience, Now It works! Thank you again!